# or that were used... -- is this grammatically fine?

Tags: tense, relative-pronouns, parallelism

Source: [Networking Bible by Barrie Sosinsky (2009)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470543426.html)

Examples:

> Copper cabling or wires, which include different categories of Ethernet cable (designated by specifications such as CAT5 or CAT6), twisted pair wiring like the ones used in your phone lines **or that were** used for smaller peer networks such as AppleTalk from Apple, and others.

I asked a native English speaker and he said that the sentence sounded fine to him, but to me it still doesn't feel like **or that were** sounds grammatically smooth there. What do you think?

Comment: "That were used" is in the wrong location. The clause should be _"twisted pair wiring like the ones **that were used** in your phone lines or for smaller peer networks such as AppleTalk from Apple, and others."_ Even there, it's doesn't exactly roll off the tongue. Please don't expect to find examplars of good English usage in technical works!

Comment: Your alternative form is correct, but I don't think the original is wrong.